# SQL for WooCommerce to determine FIRST ORDER on a particular day

Tags: sql, woocommerce

I am attempting to create an SQL query to determine the number of customer FIRST ORDERS on a particular day. I have created a SQL query that gives me orders on a given day but I have determined that the query is letting orders from customer that have ordered BEFORE my given date into the results.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    users.ID,
    users.display_name,
    MIN( orders.post_date ) AS 'first order date',
    orders.post_status AS 'status' 
FROM
    wp_users AS users
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS customer_ids ON users.ID = customer_ids.meta_value 
    AND customer_ids.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    INNER JOIN wp_posts AS orders ON customer_ids.post_id = orders.ID 
    AND orders.post_type = 'shop_order' 
    AND orders.post_status = 'wc-completed' 
WHERE   
    orders.post_date BETWEEN '2020-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2020-05-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    users.ID
ORDER BY
    MIN( orders.post_date )
```

Which yields the following results:

```
5746    Dave Shapiro        2020-05-31 06:29:39 wc-completed
7090    srcb57              2020-05-31 07:14:20 wc-completed
2407    Michael P Parks     2020-05-31 11:01:30 wc-completed
5849    Adam Lassen         2020-05-31 11:11:28 wc-completed
6706    espenzone           2020-05-31 15:28:23 wc-completed
7148    Ledyard McFadden    2020-05-31 16:35:29 wc-completed
5066    Jeff Phillips       2020-05-31 21:17:01 wc-completed
```

However, I know for a fact that customers 5066 & 6706 have orders in the past.

Is there a way to force the query to evaluate the following statement in the date range?

```
MIN( orders.post_date ) AS 'first order date'
```

I tried to add the following but get an error in GROUP BY (1111 - Invalid use of group function)

```
SELECT
    users.ID,
    users.display_name,
    MIN( orders.post_date ) AS 'first order date',
    orders.post_status AS 'status' 
FROM
    wp_users AS users
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS customer_ids ON users.ID = customer_ids.meta_value 
    AND customer_ids.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    INNER JOIN wp_posts AS orders ON customer_ids.post_id = orders.ID 
    AND orders.post_type = 'shop_order' 
    AND orders.post_status = 'wc-completed' 
WHERE   
    MIN( orders.post_date ) BETWEEN '2020-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2020-05-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    users.ID
ORDER BY
    MIN( orders.post_date )
```

OUTPUT ERROR:

```
SELECT
    users.ID,
    users.display_name,
    MIN( orders.post_date ) AS 'first order date',
    orders.post_status AS 'status' 
FROM
    wp_users AS users
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS customer_ids ON users.ID = customer_ids.meta_value 
    AND customer_ids.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    INNER JOIN wp_posts AS orders ON customer_ids.post_id = orders.ID 
    AND orders.post_type = 'shop_order' 
    AND orders.post_status = 'wc-completed' 
WHERE   
    MIN( orders.post_date ) BETWEEN '2020-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2020-05-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    users.ID
ORDER BY
    MIN( orders.post_date )
> 1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group by all the columns basically when you aggregate a value,

```
SELECT
    users.ID,
    users.display_name,
    MIN( orders.post_date ) AS 'first order date',
    orders.post_status AS 'status' 
FROM
    wp_users AS users
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS customer_ids ON users.ID = customer_ids.meta_value 
    AND customer_ids.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    INNER JOIN wp_posts AS orders ON customer_ids.post_id = orders.ID 
    AND orders.post_type = 'shop_order' 
    AND orders.post_status = 'wc-completed' 
       GROUP BY
users.ID,
users.display_name,
orders.post_status
having MIN( orders.post_date ) BETWEEN '2020-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2020-05-31 23:59:59'
ORDER BY
MIN( orders.post_date )
```

Comment: That query still outputs an error: 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Give me a moment

Comment: Please try now. You should not use WHERE clause while filtering with aggregated data. You have to use HAVING clause